# Compare two files

Tags: linux

I have 2 text files to compare on their first column. The following comm command shows the common lines from the 2 files correctly.

```
comm develop1.txt qa1.txt -12
```

But the following diff command does not show the difference as expected.

```
diff develop1.txt qa1.txt --side-by-side
```

Expected output is as follows:

```
mysql-data/webservice 280292 | mysql-data/webservice 28684
```

But these two values are not on the same line because the number in the last column are different. I do actually need to compare the numbers in side-by-side format.
How can it be achieved?

Comment: # join develop1.txt qa1.txt # is doing exactly what I am looking for. # can someone now let me know how to find the entries those are there in one file but are not in the second file?

Comment: my solution should give you those in one file but not the other. It's not as elegant as the join solution so, if someone gets that going (elegantly), ignore my answer. If not, you can use it. I'll update it to explain better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're up for something quick and dirty (not something I'd release into production but certainly okay for my own purposes):

```
for key in $(cat develop1.txt qa1.txt | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u) ; do
    devval=$(grep "^${key} " develop1.txt | awk '{print $2}')
    qa1val=$(grep "^${key} " qa1.txt | awk '{print $2}')
    if [[ "${devval}" != "${qa1val}" ]] ; then
        echo "$key: dev=[${devval}], qa=[${qa1val}]"
    fi
done
```

The first line retrieves all the unique keys from both files into a list (won't work if your keys have spaces but that's likely to make any solution harder to implement, and it doesn't appear to be the case here).

The second and third lines simply get the values for each key from the two files.

The `if` statement then prints out the key and the two values but only where the values are different.

Not pretty, not even thoroughly tested, but it may be adequate for your purposes. You do have to watch out for edge cases, like the possibility a key might exist multiple times in a file, or where the key may not be at the start of a line.

Comment: ## /mysql-data/support16 : /mysql-data/support16 5880 : /mysql-data/support16 438748 ## is it possible to suppress the lines like this? # I will like to see only the databases from one file not present in other.

Comment: @shantanuo, I've fixed it so that you don't get the key out three times (that was oversight on my part, sorry). Now the ones with only one key should containing the text `[]` (like `/mysql-data/support16: dev=[5880], qa=[]`) so you can run the script through a `| grep '\\[\\]'` to show you just those.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to do. Did you try using the `join` command? Given two files that contain only the example lines you've shown, the result would be this:

```
$ join develop1.txt qa1.txt
mysql-data/webservice 280292 28684
```

You can tell `join` to output unpairable lines with:

```
$ join -a1 -a2 develop1.txt qa1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. In other words what I am trying to do is...
# mylist=`join develop1.txt qa1.txt | awk '{print $1}'`
## join -a1 -a2 develop1.txt qa1.txt | grep -v `$mylist`
## not working!

Comment: @shantanuo - if each line has only two columns then try `join -a1 -a2 file1 file2 | awk 'NF == 2 { print; }'`

Comment: This is not helping me to understand if the values shown are from the first file or the second one.

Comment: @shantanuo then run it once with `-a1` and once with `-a2`

Answer (score 0):

I know that what I will say is not exactly what you ask, but have you tried a visual diff program? Such WinMerge (for Windows) or Meld (for Linux)? A preview of their interfaces is below (taken from google image):

**WinMerge:**

[image]

**Meld:**

[image]